# Preventing accidental directory deletion. Making an alias that contains options?

Tags: bash, directory, rm, alias

I use an alias to prevent me from accidentally deleting files, and I would like to do something similar for directories.

For files, I have the following added to my `.bashrc`:

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

I would like to also prevent myself from accidentally removing a directory, which I have tried by doing this:

```
alias rm -rf="rm -rfi"
```

and this:

```
alias "rm -rf"="rm -rfi"
```

But neither work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Best practice to avoid accidents is by training yourself and your habits, one day you could run into the system without guidance or friendly support and your habits will rule.

Comment: I agree with rook's comment.  Ever since accidentally hitting enter while typing in "rm -rf /var/" before finishing the path "www/magento/var/cache/*"  I never type "rm" without verifying I am in the deepest directory possible to do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From bash(1):

> ALIASES
>
> [... ]The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias[...]  The characters [...] and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

So aliases can only be a single word without any quoting characters.

Using both `-f` and `-i` in a call to rm also doesn't make much sense because they are somewhat contradictory(rm(1)):

> -f, --force
>                ignore nonexistent files and arguments, **never prompt**
>
> -i     **prompt before every removal**

But here's the good thing - your alias to `rm` is actually used even when you're calling `rm -r`, because the first word - `rm` - has an alias - `rm -i`, so it gets replaced by that!

```
$ alias rm
bash: alias: rm: not found
$ alias rm='rm -i'
$ mkdir test
$ rm -r test
rm: remove directory ‘test’?
```

/edit:
Raphael Ahrens also mentioned in the comments that using `-f` (force) is not neceessary to remove directories (as can be already seen in my example), `-r` (recursive) enough is alone:

> -r, -R, --recursive
>   remove directories and their contents recursively

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing `rm` is dangerous. As soon as you're on a 'box that doesn't have those aliases set up you'll do some damage.

As far as "prevent myself from accidentally removing a directory" that's the purpose of the `-r` flag to begin with.

Please don't override commands like that, you never know what assumptions scripts are going to make. If you must, choose a name other than `rm`, otherwise change something in your workflow that prevents you from using `rm -rf` with disregard.

Comment: If you want to disregard my advice, then create a script that wraps around `/usr/bin/rm` save it to `/wtf/rm` and prepend `/wtf` to your PATH like `export PATH=/wtf:$PATH`